# Is there anyway to guarantee real user registration?

Tags: authentication, bots

I would like to provide some free tokens to users on registration, I dont want bot accounts to register and get free tokens. Is there anyway to prevent this?

I would like to use phone verification, but i am not sure if its obsolete. I was able find services that provide virtual numbers such as twilio. So not sure phone verification is enough.

Do I have other options? GCP and AWS force credit card registration but thats very inconvenient to the user.

Comment: You can use google recaptcha on registration, it will prevent bots to get the free tokens

Comment: google recaptcha can be bypassed by bots

Comment: you can use Recaptcha v3, it's difficult to bypass by bots, can add a score to detect human interaction on V3 or use hcaptcha services

Comment: Looking for better solution if possible.